# How to replace Malloc with std::vector

Tags: c++

I have some memory issues in my program so i have tried to convert the mallocs i have into vectors but have been unsuccessful.

The code i currently have:

```
midimhandle_t dimensions[3], *dimensions_new;
dimensions_new = (midimhandle_t *) malloc(sizeof(midimhandle_t) * 3);
free(dimensions_new);
```

The vector replacement that does not work:

```
midimhandle_t dimensions[3], *dimensions_new;
std::vector<midimhandle_t> dimensions_new(sizeof(midimhandle_t) * 3)
```

However when i try to run my code with the replacement code i get the following error

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<midimension*>’ to ‘midimension**’
```

So my question are:
Are the creation of the vector wrong or is there something else i have to take into account?

Comment: simply `std::vector<midimhandle_t> dimensions_new(3)`. But your error spotted should come from elsewhere. Note also that you declare 2 different `dimensions_new`.

Comment: Typo; Get rid of the `*dimensions_new` in `midimhandle_t dimensions[3], *dimensions_new;`.

Comment: you're trying to redeclare your variable `midimhandle_t *dimensions_new` as `std::vector<midimhandle_t> dimensions_new` it seems? why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace this:

```
midimhandle_t dimensions[3], *dimensions_new;
std::vector<midimhandle_t> dimensions_new(sizeof(midimhandle_t) * 3);
```

with simply:

```
midimhandle_t dimensions[3];
std::vector<midimhandle_t> dimensions_new(3);
```

Comment: Please note that deleting a wrong answer and writing a new good answer is frowned upon.  The wrong answer should be edited to be correct.  See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297104/is-it-ok-to-repost-deleted-answers-as-new-answers-when-errors-have-been-correcte) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251724/is-it-ok-to-repost-deleted-answers-as-new-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
std::array<midimhandle_t, 3> dimensions;
std::vector<midimhandle_t> dimensions_new(3);
```

The first is a fixed-size, uninitialized array.  It stores its values directly inside, so if it's created on the stack the values will be too.

The second is an adjustable-size, default (value) initialized vector.  It stores its values on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your means of creating the vector is wrong, and you need to take other things into account.

Assuming your original C code looks something like

```
void some_function()
{
     midimhandle_t *dimensions_new;
     dimensions_new = (midimhandle_t *) malloc(sizeof(midimhandle_t) * 3);

      //  do something here

     free(dimensions_new);
 }
```

A rough equivalent using a `std::vector` would be

```
void some_function()
{
     std::vector<midimhandle_t> dimensions_new(3);    //  create vector with 3 elements

      //  do something here

      // the vector will cease to exist as the function returns
 }
```

Another thing to account for is that a `std::vector` is actually a C++ (templated) class, so supports a different set of operations (e.g. to access elements) than a pointer to an array allocated using `malloc()` - which means, depending on what `//  do something here` represents, that you will still get compilation errors.   You'll need to read the documentation for `std::vector` to learn how to use it effectively.